# Alexa Skills Kit trigger not available on drop down in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a simple AWS Lambda function that is triggered by the Alexa Skills Kit. I am following an Amazon made tutorial on creating the skill, etc. Unfortunately, Alexa Skills Kit is not an option on the drop down menu for the "Configure Triggers" window. I've attached a photo of what is available.

Is there anyway to get the Alexa Skills Kit to display? Is there something wrong with my account? Any suggestions would be very helpful. I am stuck at a spot that really shouldn't be causing me any issues. I have a basic account and therefore cannot get support from Amazon.

[image: Configure Triggers]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason my location defaulted to Oregon, which is not supported for ASK. Changing it to N. Virginia did the trick.

Comment: This is actually noted in the [guide](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-lambda-function). Of course, I still missed it until I came here.

Comment: This is also the case if the location defaults to Ohio. The location is listed in the top right corner of the browser

Comment: Can you go ahead and mark this as the correct answer, please

Answer (score 12):

Alexa Skills Kit as a trigger for AWS Lambda functions can be configured in any of `US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon) or EU (Ireland)` regions.

When configuring the Lambda endpoint for your skill, you can provide a `Default endpoint` as well as three other optional `geographical region endpoints` which will be called based on the customer’s location for better latency.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#h2-multiple-endpoints

Your skill configuration will be like below:

[image: lambda skill configuration]

Answer (score 6):

Select the appropriate region from the top right corner of the screen will enable 'Alexa Skills Set' as trigger for your lambda function. In this case you need to select 'Us East N. Virginia'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a new UI (developer beta) and several things (including the way to create a trigger) have changed.

Now you have to first configure your function and code and afterwards there is a menu item to set the triggers.

So either you turn off the beta mode or you have to find your way around on your own.

Just found out another important part: Don't use Safari to work with Alexa Skill development. In Chrome the tutorials match much better.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an added data point. If you just signed up for AWS you may have this problem.

You won't be able to select the Alexa Skill Set trigger like the tutorials say. You will also getting an error 'You aren't subscribed to this service' with EC2 in the rest of the error message.

New accounts can take up to 24 hours to actually be fully allowed to really exist to Amazon. Though it didn't take me that long.

In the mean time you will get strange errors, like the skill kit not working in lambda and your ARN being the wrong length when you are configuring the Alexa side.

Once you get the last email telling you you are a full fledge AWS citizen everything just starts working like it should.